# Enumerating inside multi column environment

Tags: enumerate, columns, exercises

I'm typesetting a list of high school exercises. I want create a list in the following form

> Exercise 1 Exercise 2 Exercise 3 Exercise 4
>
> Exercise 5 Exercise 6 Exercise 7 Exercise 8

I'm trying with this

```
\usepackage{multicol}
%
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Exercise 1 
\item Exercise 2 
\item Exercise 3 
\item Exercise 4 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{4}
\item Exercise 5 
\item Exercise 6 
\item Exercise 7 
\item Exercise 8 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

But this don't seem a practical way if I need typeset 50 or more exercises. Are there another way to get this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: i am not sure, what you need but try `paracol` package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol

Comment: I am wondering about the inline version of the list. Please have a look on the inline way of the `enumitem` package then

Comment: What kind of material goes in each exercise? Is each exercise a single-line item? Do some exercises have further parts? Or do some need several lines?

Comment: @cfr, all of them are exercises of a single-line, they don't have further parts.

Comment: What about using a `tabular`? It would be possible to number the exercises automatically. But you'd need to use `&` to separate items and to end the row after every fourth item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy with `tasks` package. It is very easy to customize too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}
\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[1].,label-width=1em,item-indent = 1em,column-sep =2em,after-item-skip =1ex]{exercises}[\exercise](4)
\begin{document}
\begin{exercises}
  \exercise Exercise 1
  \exercise Exercise 2
  \exercise Exercise 3
  \exercise Exercise 4
  \exercise Exercise 5
  \exercise Exercise 6
  \exercise Exercise 7
  \exercise Exercise 8
\end{exercises}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty way of making a list as I wish.

Answer (score 3):

You may also be interested in the `shortlst` package. See this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortlst}
\begin{document}

\begin{shortitemize}[]
\item Exercise 1
\item Exercise 2
\item Exercise 3
\item Exercise 4
\item Exercise 5
\item Exercise 6
\item Exercise 7
\item Exercise 8
\end{shortitemize}

\begin{shortenumerate}[]
\item Exercise 1
\item Exercise 2
\item Exercise 3
\item Exercise 4
\item Exercise 5
\item Exercise 6
\item Exercise 7
\item Exercise 8
\end{shortenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details on `shortlst`, see [here](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/table/shortlst.pdf).

Comment: (+1) Is there a `shortenumerate` as well? That might be just what the questioner is looking for...

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a `tabular`. However, you'd need to separate the items by `&` and remember to end the row after every fourth item. If you use `longtable`, page breaks are possible, and if you use `array`, you can automatically number the exercises by incrementing and printing a counter before each entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}
  \newcounter{exercise}
  \noindent\begin{longtable}{*{4}{>{\stepcounter{exercise}\makebox[1.5em]{\theexercise.\hfill}}p{.21\textwidth}}}
    Exercise 1 & Exercise 2 & Exercise 3 & Exercise 4\\
    Exercise 5 & Exercise 6 & Exercise 7 & Exercise 8\\
    Exercise 9 & Exercise 10 & Exercise 11 & Exercise 12\\
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular exercises]